# Using Maven profiles to switch between minified/uncompressed JS?

Tags: jsp, maven, minify, maven-profiles

I'm working on a Java web app that uses Maven for its build process, and has a lot of JavaScript.

What I want to do is basically have this in my JSP file:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="PRODUCTION">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/app.min.js"></script>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script2.js"></script>
    </c:otherwise
</c:choose>
```

Is this possible to do with Maven profiles?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). You can use that to overwrite properties in your resource files with their actual values.

1) Use a property file which holds the environment name. say **environment.properties** which has the below content.

```
environment.name=${environment.name}
```

Now use the below in your pom file

```
<properties>
    <environment.name>TEST</environment.name>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>PROD</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <environment.name>PROD</environment.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and specify resource filtering in your pom

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

if you run a build using this profile,

```
mvn clean install -P PROD
```

the environment.properties will be processed to

```
environment.name=PROD
```

and if you don't use this profile

```
mvn clean install
```

it will be processed to

```
environment.name=TEST
```

Now at runtime, read the **environment.name** property from **environment.properties** and use the appropriate .js file based on the property value.

OR

2) In case you don't want to read from the property file, you can filter the jsp itself.

```
<properties>
    <js.suffix></js.suffix>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>PROD</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <js.suffix>min.</js.suffix>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and set up the web resource filtering

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and add something of this sort in your jsp

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/app.${js.suffix}js"></script>
```

(Assuming that the uncompressed one is app.js and the compressed one is app.min.js)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was a bit different. I used the minify-maven-plugin and in development I use it to create a merged, but not minified app.js and when I'm in production, I use it to create a minified file. I named both of them app.js so I didn't have to change my JSP files with Maven.

For example:

```xml
<!-- Resource minification -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
  <executions>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <execution>
      <id>minify-js</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <skipMerge>false</skipMerge>
        <skipMinify>${javascript.skipMinify}</skipMinify>
        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
        <webappSourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappSourceDir>
        <jsSourceDir>assets/js</jsSourceDir>
        <jsSourceIncludes>
          <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
        </jsSourceIncludes>
        <jsFinalFile>app.js</jsFinalFile>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>minify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I use Maven profiles to switch the `${javascript.skipMinify}` property, for example:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>development</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <javascript.skipMinify>true</javascript.skipMinify>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>production</id>
  <properties>
    <javascript.skipMinify>false</javascript.skipMinify>
  </properties>
</profile>
```